# android dependency on resource variable names

Tags: android, resources, dependencies

I have very strange issues in my application.
I added a layout file with name add_new_item and i got an exception.
I was not even setting this xml file as content in any activity. And the exception was coming in a library function which was not touched. So while trying to find the root cause, i just tried to renaming the file to a name like "data_entry_form" and to the exception was gone !

After that again i am facing a strange similar issuse. I have a button with image name "add_new_itm". I have a layout with 4 buttons one of which is this button. After setting this layout if i click any of those buttons to reach another activity, change the phone orientation and comeback to this activity with 4 buttons and again press any of the button then wahtever layout is displayed, it has "add_new_item" image as background. 
ie layout with 4 buttons ( 4th one is add_new_item ) -> press button 1 take to new screen -> rotate phone-> comeback to layout with 4 buttons -> press button 1 again -> the screen will have add_new_item image as background occupying complete screen.

Now i tried just renaming the image, the button, and everything works fine.

Can you please explain this strange behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things probably happen because the fact that if you're using a library for your project, which contains layout files, the names of your layout files and the library layouts should not overlap. The compiler generates a single R.java file for both your and library layouts, and it won't be able to do it if the files have the same names. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had verified this point already and there is no clash.But i see that there are two R.java files generated . Both in gen folder but under different paths. But in my all files i am picking up the one specific to my project.I see that all new variables are getting added to both R.java files. Is this behavior right

Comment: I found some more interesting info. As i mentioned in my previous comment, my project has 2 R.java one of which is the library projects. I observe that when i add a new resource variable its getting updated in my both R.java files. Now the project R.java has a layout identifier with name "capture" and from my application i am launching this activity that sets the layout as capture. I see that the project library has another Rjjava file where capture identifier is say 0x7f030001.

Comment: Now if i define any layouts with starting a / b, the id for capture in my projects R.java will change. In this scenario, i am getting this unexpected behaviour. I am not still clear on 1. why my project creates two R.java file 2. How this dependency is coming.

Comment: Since your answer took me in the right direction i am accepting it.